# Extract Date time from the Sentence in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am stuck in the extracting the datetime from the sentence or format.

```
Posted on Thursday, May 1st, 2014 at 10:07 AM

2014-06-20T02:11:06+00:00
```

Is there any good regex or tool in C# where i can find out datetime from these formats.

Comment: what do you mean by extracting `datetime?` you want to convert the date `string` into `datetime` datatype?

Comment: Are these strings? If so, you can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact(String, String[], IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This method takes _string array_ as a `format` part. That's why you can give your custom formats as an array.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi but the Date string may contain other words like Posted on, at etc

Comment: @SonerGönül How can I give custom format for the first example                `Posted on Thursday, May 1st, 2014 at 10:07 AM`

Comment: Is there one standard date format to find?

Comment: @MillerKoijam There is no custom format for your `Posted on`, `1st`, and `at` parts in your string. You need to provide them as a _string delimeter_. For the others, take a look at [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: I am not sure how my date and time information would be because the posted date of the article/news is fetched from different sites.

Comment: @MillerKoijam: check my answer below to extract the actual datetime parts and forming a valid `datetime` type from it.

Comment: But how can you ever extract that information for all those different formats, especially when it is mixed up with just some random text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can do it simply with DateTime.ParseExact():

```
string ds = "Posted on Thursday, May 1st, 2014 at 10:07 AM";

string[] formats = new string[] {
"MMMM d'st, 'yyyy' at 'hh:mm tt",   // for parsing like "1st"
"MMMM d'nd, 'yyyy' at 'hh:mm tt",   // for parsing like "2nd"
"MMMM d'rd, 'yyyy' at 'hh:mm tt",   // for parsing like "3rd"
"MMMM d'th, 'yyyy' at 'hh:mm tt",   // for parsing like "4th"
};

// Get rid of the "Posted on Thursday"
ds = ds.Substring(ds.IndexOf(", ") + 2);
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(ds, formats, null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);

// Once you have a DateTime, you can format it any way you want
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("o"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to split the string and extract the required parts.

below solution only works when the string is in the form of 
    `Posted on Thursday, May 1st, 2014 at 10:07 AM`

Try This:

```
string datestring = "Posted on Thursday, May 1st, 2014 at 10:07 AM";
var dateParts = datestring.Split();
var day=dateParts[2].Replace(",","");
var month=dateParts[3];
var date=dateParts[4].Replace("st","").Replace("nd","").Replace("rd","")
                                              .Replace("th","").Replace(",","");
var year=dateParts[5];
var hoursminutes=dateParts[7];
var AMorPM=dateParts[8];

//format d-MMMM-yyyy h:mm tt
string editedDate=date+"-"+month+"-"+year+" "+hoursminutes+" "+AMorPM;
DateTime finalDate = DateTime.ParseExact(editedDate, "d-MMMM-yyyy h:mm tt", 
                                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @MillerKoijam: Yes, Other answers are even better :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom function and use [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to parse the date using [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public DateTime ParseDateTime(string dt)
{
    DateTime d;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dt, "'Posted on' dddd, MMM d'st', yyyy 'at' hh:mm tt" , null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d))  
        return d;   
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dt, "'Posted on' dddd, MMM d'nd', yyyy 'at' hh:mm tt", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
        return d;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dt, "'Posted on' dddd, MMM d'rt', yyyy 'at' hh:mm tt", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
        return d;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dt, "'Posted on' dddd, MMM d'th', yyyy 'at' hh:mm tt", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
        return d;

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Not a valid DateTime string");
}
```

There are few things that need explanation in the datetime string you have.

1. A literal Posted on, which could be parse by enclosing in single quote.
2. 1st, which is parse using d'st' and this will apply to 2nd, 3rd, 4th and so on.